# Displaying users from a database in php?

Tags: php, database

The name of the table is 'Users' and the column is 'First Name' & 'Last Name'

I want to display all on one page and only 5 users on another? How do I accomplish this in PHP?

PS. The header is connecting to the database.

UPDATE: I am fairly new to PHP, sorry for the question being so vague. I figured it out. Thanks everyone.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: *"and the column is 'First Name' & 'Last Name'"* - be careful with that. *Right Sam?* - @JayBlanchard

Comment: *Righto Ralph!* There is a lot of care that needs to be taken here @Fred-ii-

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this if you are using mysqli:

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mybd") 
or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection)); 

$sql = mysqli_query($connection, 'SELECT * FROM Users')
         or die(mysqli_error($connection));

while($user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    print_r($user);
}
```

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

---

**Important sidenote:**

You also state:

> *and the column is 'First Name' & 'Last Name'*

Be careful when using spaces between words for column names.

If you end up using them in your query, you will need to use ticks around them, or rename them using underscores.

I.e.:

This will error out:

```
SELECT First Name, Last Name FROM Users
```

as will

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE First Name = 'John'
```

therefore, you need to wrap those columns in ticks:

```
SELECT `First Name`, `Last Name` FROM Users
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE `First Name` = 'John'
```

or rename them to `First_Name` and `Last_Name` *respectively*.

> *and only 5 users on another*

You can use LIMIT.

I.e.:

```
SELECT * FROM Users LIMIT 5
```

Comment: [there's an error here. no connection to the query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) - `$sql = mysqli_query('SELECT * FROM Users');`

Comment: You've to do the connection. Are you using `mysql` or `mysqli` connection in the header you're mentioning?

Comment: @Fred-ii- This is kinda vague but OP said: `PS. The header is connecting to the database.`. Which I assume means that he already has the connection himself.

Comment: ^ yeah, we just don't know which API the OP is using.

Comment: @Loko vague? lol ok. I think this person shouldn't assume, and the answer doesn't work "as is".

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yeah what OP said is vague. Not your comment.

Comment: @Loko lol my bad. *I gave myself a slap* hehe *ouch*, that ought to teach me.

Comment: Ah, it wasn't the questioner asking me the question. Now I see.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Not your fault. I see how my comment can be confusing.

Comment: @Loko No problemo and I fixed the answer.